# awk or sed to create new file?

Tags: sed, awk

I have a pipe-delimited text file containing about 900 rows of data.  Each row contains a set of numbers with a username at the end.  e.g.

```
2792|5750|125|4.0|0.25|||6|2|user1
2802|6000|126|4.0|0.25|||2|3|user2
2801|6000|125|4.0|0.25|||4|4|user2
2805|5500|125|4.5|0.25|||3|2|user1
2805|6250|122|4.5|0.25|||4|7|user3
2811|4750|125|3.0|0.25|||4|2|user1
2828|5750|121|4.0|0.25|||6|2|user2
```

What I would like to do is create three new files: one for each of the users, containing only their data.  (e.g. the file for user1 would contain only the first, fourth, and sixth line of the original file). Should I use awk or sed to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way:

```
awk -F "|" '{ print > $NF }' file
```

Here's the results of `grep . user*`:

```
user1:2792|5750|125|4.0|0.25|||6|2|user1
user1:2805|5500|125|4.5|0.25|||3|2|user1
user1:2811|4750|125|3.0|0.25|||4|2|user1
user2:2802|6000|126|4.0|0.25|||2|3|user2
user2:2801|6000|125|4.0|0.25|||4|4|user2
user2:2828|5750|121|4.0|0.25|||6|2|user2
user3:2805|6250|122|4.5|0.25|||4|7|user3
```

Also, some people like to add a file extension. This can be done like:

```
awk -F "|" '{ print > $NF ".txt" }' file
```

Comment: My awk is a little rusty, did you want `>>` there? Otherwise very nice.

Comment: That's actually a common misconception. `awk` holds its file handles open until it's finished. But it could be written either way really.

Comment: @MeganCrane: Don't forget to accept an answer if it has worked for you. Cheers.

Comment: @steve , i tried that i am getting this error `' (Protocol error)p.txt FNR=1) fatal: can't redirect to user1`

Comment: @user19340357: TBH, I'm not 100% sure what's causing you grief. However, if you are using `BSD awk`, you may need to create a variable first. Try: `awk -F "|" '{ x = $NF ".txt"; print > x }' file`. HTH.

Comment: @user19340357: Interesting problem. I don't think I've seen a "protocol error" before. I'd check a few things, like your filename - does it contain any strange characters. Does your file contain windows newline endings - if so run `dos2unix yourfile`. Could your `awk` installation be broken? What version of `awk` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Why not `grep`?

```
grep user1 bigfile > file_for_user1
grep user2 bigfile > file_for_user2
grep user3 bigfile > file_for_user3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for THEUSER in `cat file | awk -F'|' '{print $10}' | sort | uniq`; do grep $THEUSER file > $THEUSER; done
```

Comment: You might want to explain what you're doing here a little bit, so it's more broadly applicable than solving this particular question.